# enumitem not working with foilhead

Tags: enumitem

Is there any way to get, say, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 in the following enumeration? I keep getting error ! Missing number, treated as zero.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerfoils}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}

\begin{document}
\foilhead{tst}
\begin{enumerate}[label=10.\arabic*.]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{enumerate}
\endfoil
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with new information that could be of interest for you.

Comment: Certainly it is of great use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use `enumitem` and `beamer`; the former takes control over lists and overlay specifications and special `beamer` formatting are lost, for example.

You can locally redefine `\theenumi`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerfoils}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}

\begin{document}
\foilhead{tst}
{
\renewcommand\theenumi{10.\arabic{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{enumerate}
}
\endfoil
\end{document}
```

[image]

I commented out the line loading the `Copenhagen` theme, since this theme uses small circles to accomodate tha labes and the default spacing for labels is not enoufh for three digits.

You can, of course, keep the `Copenhagen` theme by locally redefining the `enumerate items` template to use the `default` option (thus suppressing the small circles):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerfoils}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\begin{document}
\foilhead{tst}
{
\renewcommand\theenumi{10.\arabic{enumi}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{enumerate}
}
\endfoil
\end{document}
```

[image]